# geom_rect( ) not working over Dates

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a shaded bar over a variable that is moving in a time series with Dates on the x-axis.

I am using `geom_rect()` for this. If the days are numbered on the x-axis I have no issues but when there are Dates on the x-axis I get the following error:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

I have tried to change the xmax from Inf to 100, but nothing seems to work. The data is arranged in this format:

```
set.seed(333)
Start.Date <- as.Date("2015-05-01")
Date <- Start.Date + 0:40 
variable.1 <- rnorm(n = Date, mean = 720, sd = 300)
df <- data.frame(Date, variable.1)
df

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = variable.1)) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = Inf, ymin = 500, ymax = 1100), fill = "blue", alpha = .2) +
    geom_point() + geom_line()
```

Thanks for any help. I'm sure I am missing something

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

If I keep the xmin and xmax out of aes() it will produce the graph just fine.

Comment: Generally, only names of data columns should go inside `aes()`. In your example where you only want one rectangle, `annotate(geom = "rect", ...)` is probably preferable.